# Two stage Amplifier CC-CE with high voltage gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I want to design a two stage amplifier with the following parameters: Av = 300, Zi = 1M, VCC = +12V. I have tried deriving the parameters to use but have not been successful as my lecturer always said I'm wrong. He said it has to be CC-CE which I'm a little bit confused. 
I would be grateful if someone could help me in any way you can. Thank you.

Comment: Post the schematic of your best attempt, with your reasoning why you think it should meet the spec.

Comment: Why do you think the CC stage should be first and the CE stage last? (Hint: turn the parameters around Zi, Av)

Comment: Zout is always assumed to be low in a useful design

Comment: What frequency range are you wishing to cover (3 dB points)? You won't get a gain of 300 with low distortion with one transistor in CE irrespective of where the other CC is placed.

Comment: You also need a spec BW Vin max, THD, hFE and Zout but, ....Q1= CE then Q2=CC  thus emitter Ze1= 2e6/hFE1 , Zb1=2e6 then Zin=1e6, Av=Zc/Ze=hfE*Ze2//Rc1/2e6*hFE1

Comment: Starting the close process due to inadequate specs.  What frequency range?  What output impedance?  Also, we are not here to do your homework for you.  We can help with specific things you are stuck on, but we're certainly not going to design a whole discrete amplifier for you, even if we knew what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : I agree with you. This kind of questions are usually closed (as I know) or down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't want to put up the 'full solution' as I think the OP will benefit from working through the design themselves.

A two stage amplifier is simply a combination of two single stages. In this case a common collector (CC) followed by a common emitter (CE)

[image]

This is the generic circuit. The output of the first stage is connected to the input of the second stage.

Task 1 is to work out what values are required in the CC stage to give a 1M0 input impedance.

Task 2 is to work out what values in the CE stage are required to give a voltage amplification of 300.

You can assume that the BJTs are of the jelly bean variety (common types such as the BC458 etc.) and they have a minimum current gain of 100.

Not asked for in the question BUT the values of the capacitors will control the frequency range of the amplifier. Assume C1 is 0.1uF, C2 is 10uF and C3 is 100uF and C4 is 100uF and for the purposes of any gain calculations their impedances can be ignored (Zc = 0).

There are plenty of sites in the internet that will take you through the design steps.

Comment: Voltage gain of 300 is unreasonable to get from a single common-emitter transistor stage.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree but not impossible. I didn't set the initial question, I'm just trying to help the guy through the process as he's obviously struggling.

Comment: Thnk you Sir@ Jim Dearden you have really broken it down for me  because i was very confused majorly in deriving the parameters to use i think it your explanation i now know where to start. where i wud be confused would be how to get my Q-Point for the first stage and Maximum collector current for both stages. all infact tell me the major parameters to find in other for the cct to work. Thanks Sir

Comment: The only bit of extra advice I'll give is you need to set Rc in the CE amp at 300 x re (where re is the "Emitter Leg Signal Resistance") see http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/input-impedance-of-an-amplifier.html. A typical value for re is 25R making Rc = 7.5K. The voltage at the collector should be about 7V (to give maximum swing) and Re should drop about 10% (1.2V) giving Vb = Ve + 0.7 (=1.9V). This gives all the information you need to make simple (Ohm's law type) calculations.  I won't give any more help or do it for you.

Comment: you have done well Sir! i really appreciate

Comment: @Jim Dearden  I'm sorry for stressing you but I'm still new to the Electronics system and I'm trying to learn the hard way. the major concern of mr Lecturer is to show all working and from the  link you sent, I used the example from  Common Emitter for the CC but my lecturer said its wrong. and has refused to give me clues. please try to solve for the first Stage i think i can manage from there. thnks Sir

Comment: sincerely i wish i can be your student

Comment: CC calc is not the same as CE. The input resistance of a common collector circuit is effectively (1+ beta) *Re where beta is the current gain of the transistor (take that to be 100 for small signal transistor). For maximum voltage swing, the emitter voltage wants to be at about 1/2 supply. To make things easy choose 5.3V (makes Vb = 6V, so both base resistors can be equal). To get a 1M0 input we need to use higher value resistors for R1,R2, say 4M7 each. In parallel these produce about 2M4. To get 1M0 the input resistance of the CE must be  1M7. R3 is therefore 101 times smaller or about 17k.

Comment: that should have said "to get 1M0 the input resistance of the **CC** must be 1M7. Note that the bias resistors R1,R2 and the input resistor of the CC are all in parallel.

Comment: The MOST GAIN you can get from a CE stage is VDD/0.026v. Here, that is 12/0.026 or 12*39, approximately 468. This means the Qpoint will be very uncentered, and the stage is easily pushed into asymmetric distortion.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf and as 300 (the gain asked for by the OP) < 468 then that's OK. Its only a homework question to practice calculations on and not a real circuit to use.